# What does "You just better had" mean in this context?

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> "Harry, you'd better beat him in the Quidditch final!" Hermione said shrilly. "**You just better had**, because I can't stand it if Slytherin wins!"

I don't quite understand "*You just better had*" in this context. I can't find a reference in dictionaries. What does it truly mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's elliptical, understanding the presence of the verb + object from the prior statement.

> You just better had [beat him]

Comment: It is also a rephrasing of the prior statement for emphasis: *"You'd better"* or *"You had better"* becomes *"You [just] better had"*.

Comment: @LeeMac, It seems to be a kind of wordplay here. ..

Comment: There's no wordplay, @dan.  This is an everyday speech pattern.

Comment: Shouldn't be "You just better had [**beaten** him]"?

Comment: No, admonitory **had** is complemented by the bare infinitive.  *I had better **go***.  = "I should go" or "I really ought to leave now".

Comment: Hmmm, I'm confused. I know "you had better + bare infinitive", but not "you better had + bare infinitive". Are "had better" and "better had" the same?

Comment: I'd consider **...you just better had!** Brit-speak. In AmE we would say "You better beat him...you just better!" or "You'd better beat him....you'd just better!". But in either case it is ellipsis.

Comment: That's something interesting to know. I can only find "had better" on the web, not "better had".

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo *"Brit-speak"* I'd agree with that :-)

Comment: @dan: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=you+better+had%2Cthey+better+had%2Cwe+better+had&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cyou%20better%20had%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthey%20better%20had%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwe%20better%20had%3B%2Cc0 Search against Google Books, not against websites.